# Why is Netbeans complaining about my GNUmakefile?

Tags: netbeans, makefile, gnu-make

I am making a Netbeans C++ project with an existing GNUmakefile. I went to File -> New Project -> C/C++ with Existing Sources and selected the folder with my current files (including the GNUmakefile).

However, when I run my app, I get the following error.

```
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `Makefile'. Stop.

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 67 ms)
```

I suspect that my Makefile is named "GNUmakefile", which differs from "Makefile." However, I do not want to rename "GNUmakefile," since I am working on this project with others who want to keep it the same.

Is that why Netbeans complains about my GNUmakefile? How can I tell Netbeans to use GNUmakefile instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you must be invoking make as `make -f Makefile`, so you are explicitly (whether you realize it or not) saying to use a makefile called `Makefile`.  Otherwise, GNU make would happily use GNUmakefile:

```
$ ls
GNUmakefile
$ cat GNUmakefile
all: ; @echo done
$ make
done
$ make -f Makefile
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `Makefile'.  Stop.
```

Note that you only get the error you reported in the last case.  So you just need to change how you are invoking GNU make.  Alternatively you could symlink `Makefile` to `GNUmakefile`:

```
$ ln -s GNUmakefile Makefile
$ gmake -f Makefile
done
```